# My Android application is not visible on market with Motorola Xoom

Tags: android, google-play, xoom

I have an Android application with `android:minSdkVersion="7"`, but on the Market is not visible for Motorola Xoom.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you give us more details?  If you visit your apps page online [link](http://market.android.com), does it let you install from there?  What does it say? Did you publish it using "Copy Protection"?  Are you using a custom ROM?

Comment: We can't help you with seeing your AndroidManifest.xml file, can you post it?

Comment: I found solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761354/application-not-installable-on-motorola-xoom-from-android-marketplace

Answer (score 0):

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```